# NotFoundHttpException in laravel 4.2 given when model update

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

i am receving this error in laravel 4.2.*

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

when i am updating a record.

// Routing

```
Route::get('projects/edit/{slug}', array('as' => 'projects.edit', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@edit'));
Route::put('projects/update?{slug}', array('as' => 'projects.update', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@update'));
```

// Controller

```
public function update($slug){
    $pr = $this->project->whereSlug($slug)->first();
    $this->project->fill(Input::all());
    $this->project->save();
}
```

// Form

```
{{ Form::model($project, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['projects.update', project->slug ],'files' => true]) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

// URL

```
pms2.dev/projects/update?slug
```

hope someone know, why i am facing this.

Comment: please provide your url

Comment: #worldask url updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace your routing as follow

```
Route::patch('projects/update', array('as' => 'projects.update', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@update'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your form's method is set to `PATCH` then your route should also be defined with the same verb.

```
Route::patch('projects/update?{slug}', array('as' => 'projects.update', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@update'));
```

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_patch

However i think POST is the more appropriate method here.